# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "no es moco de pavo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos, expresiones

El Diccionario de la RAE define [**moco de pavo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PT8MVi9) como

> 1. m. Apéndice carnoso y eréctil que tiene el pavo sobre el pico.
>
> 2. m. Planta herbácea de adorno, de la familia de las amarantáceas, con tallo grueso, verde, ramoso, de algo más de un metro de altura, hojas aovadas lampiñas y flores generalmente purpúreas, dispuestas en grupos de espigas colgantes alrededor de otra central más larga.
>
> 3. m. Méx. amaranto (‖ planta).

y más adelante (gracias Carlos Alejo por señalarlo) [**no ser algo moco de pavo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PT8MVi9):

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Ser de importancia.

¿Cómo y cuándo adquirió ese sentido figurado?

Comment: En el diccionario de autoridades, tomo de 1734, ya aparece la expresión en forma de pregunta (¿es moco de pavo?) para preguntar la estimación o entidad de algo que se cree despreciable. No dice el origen, pero creo que se debe entender literalmente: el moco de pavo es la parte menos valiosa del mismo.

Comment: En http://dedondeviene.blogspot.com.es/2007/09/no-es-moco-de-pavo.html y en http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/no-es-moco-de-pavo.306603/ dan una explicación diferente: del robo del reloj de bolsillo de la víctima (_el pavo_), dejando solo la cadena colgando como el apéndice del ave...

Comment: Esa historia del reloj se ve en muchas webs pero ninguna, que yo haya visto,  cita las fuentes. A mi esa explicación me parece un tanto forzada aunque eso no significa que no sea cierta.

Answer (score 4):

Esta respuesta debe ser tomada con cautela, dado que es mera especulación. Aparte del origen mencionado en los comentarios, por el cual la expresión debe entenderse literalmente al ser el moco de pavo la parte menos importante y menos valiosa del animal, podría haber una explicación un poco más erótico-festiva.

> *Quedaba un musulmán de bigotazos
>
>   que quitaba los virgos a porrazos
>
>   engendrador a roso y a velloso
>
>   y eterno atacador del sexo hermoso.
>
>   Éste, pues, embistió con la beata,
>
>   ella en sus movimientos se desata;
>
>   él se procura asir con fuerte mano
>
>   y su giro burlar, pero fue en vano,
>
>   que al choque impetuoso
>
>   el árabe rijoso
>
>   se sintió vacilante y, reculando,
>
>   perdió su dirección allí luchando.
>
>   Empeine con empeine compitieron,
>
>   el choque repitieron,
>
>   y al golpe la erección del moro bravo
>
>   vino a quedar en un **moco de pavo**.*
>
> - Felix María Samaniego, "[El jardín de Venus](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/el-jardin-de-venus--0/html/ffc4efae-82b1-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_3.html#I_89_)", España (a 1797)

La expresión "ser moco de pavo" ya viene recogida en el primer diccionario de la RAE, el de autoridades, en 1734, antes de escribirse este poema. Sin embargo, esta historia podría apuntar a un origen del término por el cual un miembro que parezca "un moco de pavo" es inútil, no sirve para su función procreadora, y por tanto no tendría valor.

Otro ejemplo del mismo libro:

> *En la ciudad alegre y renombrada
>
>   que riega, saltarín, Guadalmedina,
>
>   empezó a padecer de mal de orina
>
>   una recién casada
>
>   de edad de veinte años,
>
>   a quien vinieron semejantes daños
>
>   de que su viejo esposo,
>
>   setentón lujurioso,
>
>   por más esfuerzos que a su lado hacía
>
>   y con sus refregones la impelía
>
>   al conyugal recreo,
>
>   jamás satisfacía su deseo,
>
>   quedando a media rienda el pobrecito
>
>   con un **moco de pavo** tan maldito,
>
>   que la moza, volada,
>
>   enfermó de calor. ¡Ahí que no es nada!*

Así que cuando alguien tiene algo que "no es moco de pavo", imaginaos lo que tiene. En todo caso, esta alegoría de comparar el moco de pavo con cosas flácidas no es nueva. También tenemos este otro texto, bastante anterior:

> *Incorpóranse a la procesión, que se va componiendo de alumbrantes tarascas; y por el camino va uno, empleándose en dar con el capirote a cuantos pobretes ve, hasta que al dar a uno se le ase y quita de la cabeza, con que descubre una cara de tarasca vinosa, obligándole a dar el hacha a otro, en cuanto se pone el capirote ya hecho pedazos, que al levantarle se le cae la mitad a las espaldas, quedando como **moco de pavo**.*
>
> - Francisco Santos, "Las tarascas de Madrid", España (1665)

En este caso lo que se compara es un capirote, que tendría que estar tieso y apuntando hacia arriba, pero que en vez de eso se ha quedado colgando por detrás, sobre la espalda, perdiendo así su majestuosidad el portador del mismo (quedando sin importancia). Lo cual podría dar algo más de validez a la teoría.

Comment: De la [sugerencia de edición](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12007): tanto _flácido_ como _fláccido_ son correctas.

Comment: @fedorqui extraído [del DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=fl%C3%A1cido): "La forma etimológica _fláccido_ (del lat. _flaccidus_), aún mayoritaria en la escritura, es válida, pero resulta preferible, por su simplicidad gráfica y articulatoria, la forma _flácido_. Lo mismo cabe decir de los sustantivos _flacidez_ y _flaccidez_." Me la apunto.

Answer (score 1):

El **amaranto o moco de pavo era la base de la alimentación tolteca**, el que se le diera ese apodo indica que ser moco de pavo era algo usado, como en las expresiones antes citadas, pero lo que hay que explicar parece más bien el **por qué algo NO es moco de pavo**, y quizá ahí pueda haber intervenido la referencia al amaranto, que cuando no se cultiva sistemáticamente es más bien una mala hierba, pero en cambio puede (por tanto es mera hipótesis, pero para mí mejor que la del reloj) que los españoles encontraran que aún se consumía en México y por su escaso valor **prefirieran otros alimentos** que no fueran moco de pavo.